# Recharts Radar - Invalid Value for <line> attribute x1=NaN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to get a radar chart in React Recharts. My data looks like:

```
[{N_DNA: 2, T_DNA: 1, T_RNA: 3, subject: "A1"},
{N_DNA: 1, T_DNA: 3, T_RNA: 2, subject: "A2"},
{N_DNA: 4, T_DNA: 4, T_RNA: 1, subject: "B1"},
{N_DNA: 6, T_DNA: 8, T_RNA: 7, subject: "B2"}]
```

My React code is:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width={"95%"} height={"100%"}>
                    <RadarChart
                        cx={300}
                        cy={250}
                        outerRadius={150}
                        width={500}
                        height={500}
                        data={data}
                    >
                        <PolarGrid />
                        <PolarAngleAxis dataKey="subject" />
                        <PolarRadiusAxis />
                        <Radar
                            name="Mike"
                            dataKey="N_DNA"
                            stroke="red"
                            fill="none"
                            fillOpacity={0.3}
                        />
                        <Radar
                            name="Jake"
                            dataKey="T_DNA"
                            stroke="blue"
                            fill="none"
                            fillOpacity={0.3}
                        />
                        <Radar
                            name="Jake"
                            dataKey="T_RNA"
                            stroke="green"
                            fill="none"
                            fillOpacity={0.3}
                        />
                    </RadarChart>
                </ResponsiveContainer>
```

When I try to recreate this in code sandbox, it works fine. But it throws an error on the browser.

The error is `Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute x1="NaN"`

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-radar-chart-forked-mkieb8?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Well. Your test example works in code sandbox; I tested it with recharts version 2.2.0 to check for the latest recharts version support, as well. Do you have the same recharts version (or version 2.2.0) as in the sandbox installed in your local project? 
Otherwise it looks like the issue is in your project code.

Comment: yep I have version 2.2.0 in my project. I tried using the same code (and data) from the sandbox and no data shows up. Do you know if this an issue with just radial charts? My other Scatter and Bar Charts are loading fine